# Circles drawn mainly in X an Y axises, WHY?

Tags: java, math, processing

[image]

I have created a loop using processing that  draws circles, the overall shape should be a circle. However they are mainly drawn close to X and Y axis. I have randomized the angle for the calculus of its location, I cannot see where the problem is.

Code as follows:

```
for (int omega = 0; omega<1080; omega++){  //loop for circle creation
    radius = (int)random(80);   //random radius for each circle

    int  color1= (int)random(100);  //little variation of color for each circle
    int  color2= (int)random(100);

        int locationY = (int)(sin(radians(omega))*random(width/2+1)); //location calcualtion
        int locationX = (int)(cos(radians(omega))*random(width/2+1));
        fill(0,color1+200,color2+200,50);
        ellipse(locationX,locationY,radius,radius); //draw circles
    }
```

Comment: Wich random implementation do you use ? The normal build in is sometimes prone to cluster values. Try using another seed or try another random implementation. There are a couple of real good ones. Try googling for Mersenne Twister, it is a real good one and you can find plenty implementations for java.

Comment: What does "close to X and Y axis" mean? Can you provide a screenshot? Upload it to imgur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good point @Durandal (+1)

However I have one more thought with random circles.

When you generate random distance with such code:

```
double distance = random( width/2  );
```

you random from **uniform distribution**. I mean all values from `0` to `width/2` have the **same probability**. But circle with `3*r` radius have `9` times bigger area then circle with `r` radius. So, the smaller distance from center, the greater density we can see.

This way generated *cloud* **do not have uniform density** as you can see on first image.
[image]

But if you change the **probability density function** in such way that bigger values are less probable that smaller ones you can get uniformly generated cloud.

Such simple modification:

```
double distance = Math.sqrt( random( width/2 * width/2 ) );
```

produces more uniformly distributed circles, as you can see on second image.
[image]

I hope this can be helpful..

Comment: Good point, and very nicely demonstrated with the pictures +1

Answer (score 5):

Its an artefact of the way you calculate location, you're pulling *two* different random values for the X and Y component:

```
int locationY = (int)(sin(radians(omega))*random(width/2+1)); //location calcualtion
int locationX = (int)(cos(radians(omega))*random(width/2+1));
```

You should use *one* random value "distance" from the center for both X and Y, that will remove the clustering towards the axes.